# A problem invoving continuous function, compact set etc.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $K$ and $F$ are disjoint sets in a metric space $X$, $K$ is compact, $F$ is closed. I need to prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(p,q) > \delta$ if $p \in K, q \in F$.

But from the fact that $0$ can't be a limit point of the set $\rho_F(K)$ where $\rho_F(x) =inf_{z \in F} d(x,z)$ defined on $K$, we can only say that $d(p,q) \geq \delta$. I can't understand how to get rid of the equal to case.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon = \inf\limits_{x\in K} d(x,F)$ and choose $\delta = \varepsilon/2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I did not understand that. What we can say is that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $p \in K, q \in F$  $d(p,q) \geq \delta$. But the question asks to prove that $d(p,q) \gt \delta$.

Comment: The question says to prove that _there is some_ $\delta > 0$, such that ... . Just don't choose $\delta$ as the distance between $K$ and $F$, that would only give you $\geqslant$, **choose _any_ smaller number**.

Comment: @DanielFischer: sorry this was trivial.

Comment: Don't be sorry, we all know that duh-moment. Once you started looking at it from a wrong angle for only a split second, you can't unconvince yourself that $4\cdot 4 = 12$.